# Controller security

Tags: microcontroller, security

What is the general approach used by the military to safeguard controllers that fall into enemy hands?

Let's say the controller needs to interpret radio / wireless signals to do it's job. But it could be any job I suppose.

What approach is used to prevent reverse engineering of the logic that interprets the signals? Or more generally, how can hardware do it's job but not be reverse-engineer-able or susceptible to re-purposing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This all comes down to destructibility of the functional structure.

As in break-in prevention for homes, usually the safety of a structure is thought of in effort needed to get in, not "absolute impossibility", since a large army of engineers can always find a way to get around what a couple of them invented as protection.

There are several ways to reverse engineer:

- One is just reading the memory. This one is quite simple and also reasonably easy to protect against. Since a processor or memory device can include encryption for the communication with any other device and a structure that destroys the data when the wrong interfacing is used.
- Another is cutting open a chip and "looking" at what's inside. You can protect against that through structures of metal and wiring that rip the insides apart when it gets "scalped".
- Yet another method is using acids or strong bases (chemical kind, not transistor) to dissolve the main package and again looking at it. For this protection is harder, but generally if this is a danger, vital structures are included that are highly susceptible to moisture or other required chemicals, or very strongly chemical resistant layers can be included in the packaging.
- The last one I can think of, top of my head, is using imaging technologies that look through stuff, such as X-ray diffraction techniques and such. Usually the metal structures used for the "ripping apart" option will scatter and glare so much on many of these techniques that no further action is needed.

I'm sure there are more that I haven't ever considered before (because I earn my living by ways other than hacking other people's work), but usually there are many ways of protection against them. But many are expensive and the game of chance of the device falling in the wrong hands and needing those protections is a very strongly balanced one.